# How to set firestore timestamp data to a TextView

Tags: android-studio, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a timestamp field in firebase firestore which is in this format "**10 February 2019 at 00:05:10 UTC+5:30**"

Now, I want to display this data in TextView as **10-10-2019**

I have googled it but not getting any solution. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

I have just used below 3 lines and my issue resolved.

```
java.util.Date dateFromServer = sometimestampdata.toDate();
String formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(dateFromServer);
textview.setText(formatter);

Output : 21-05-2018
```